# Is there a correlation between brain size and amount of sleep?

Tags: brain, sleep, circadian-rhythms

As far as we know, sleep seems to be the part of the daily cycle when executive functions are resting and memories are fortifying. Many, but not all, of the functions that become dysfunctional upon sleep deprivation seem to be situated in the frontal lobe or associated with the neocortex.

My question is whether there is a correlation between percentage of the day spent sleeping and brain size (either the whole brain, or a part of the brain such as the neocortex or frontal lobe). How do other species correlate compared to us? Either in absolute brain size, or in brain size relative to body size.

Comment: I'm closing this question as it is cross-posted on CogSci already at http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/is-there-a-correlation-between-brain-size-and-amount-of-sleep

Comment: @MadScientist not sure, they're complaining about the cross-posting over there too and neither one has an answer. I'm not sure which site is a better fit. Darko, could you please modify your question  to fit the different communities more specifically?

Comment: Changing the question would not alter the outcome and as such is stupid. But ok. Since the question is more specific towards the correlation between species, I will leave it as it is here. Cognitive scientists have nothing to add to that. I will edit the Q on CogSci to make it a better fit.